# Watch multiple directories for file creation; Email if they don't exist

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I have a somewhat tricky question. I need to monitor a group of files to see if a a series of files have been created within them. I would like to monitor the files roughly every 10 minutes and report via email if the any files have NOT been created. This seems somewhat easy to do via find, and I was thinking of doing something such as this where I find the files with a modify time of 10 minutes and seeing how many change every ten minutes (should be around 10 or so.)

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -mmin -10 -ls  2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

The problem, I'm having is the times aren't exactly 10 minutes, sometimes it's a little more, sometimes a little less. Also, I've been asked to not only check the times, but the file names which will have a time stamp in them such as processa_15:30 (and processb_15:30 in another directory, and so on).

I believe inotifywait would be useful for something like this, but it isn't installed and I don't think I will be able to have it installed. I would prefer to do this with bash or Perl and it is on a CentOS 6.0 system. But, I will also probably not be able to install any Perl modules to do this with. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you schedule a cronjob for every 10 min to run a proper `find`.
Also if you can update the question on criteria you have to find those files, are you finding all files in particular dir?

Comment: Have a look at AIDE, it is very helpful:
http://www.snekul.com/wordpress/blog/2012/09/27/using-aide-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-and-debian-7-wheezy/

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to monitor number of files created have you thought about making a script that checks number of files like you did with find, sleeps for ~10 minutes (if they're a little more or little less work out your limits i.e. +-30 seconds), checks and compares the two numbers and loops? That way you could use something like this as a function:

```
find1=`find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -mmin -10 -ls  2>/dev/null | wc -l`
sleep 600
find2=`find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -mmin -10 -ls  2>/dev/null | wc -l`

if [ "$find1" == "$find2" ]; then
    echo "no new files..." | mail -s "$date : Alert" user@domain.com
else 
    exit
fi
```

That way you could compare the two numbers and if no change then email.

To add limit of +-30s maybe run the find and assign number to variable 30s before and after find1 and find2, and you can generate extra conditions like if find1=find2, but the numbers differ within 30s before and after, then email.

You could also put in further checks into the if loop based on filename timestamp etc with if AND etc.

This way you could just run the function in a loop continuously.